# rails start create form url wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i flowed [rails getting_started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

in the 5.2 section “The first form”，the

http://localhost:3000/articles/new

[image: success form]

works fine before i add form “, url: create” how can i resolve this problem？

when i add url the result is：

[image]

and the rails run environment is：

> ➜  blog  bin/rake routes

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
```

welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index

```
     root GET    /                            welcome#index

 articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index

          POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
```

new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new

edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit

```
  article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show

          PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update

          PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update

          DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

➜  blog  ruby -v

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

➜  blog  sqlite3 --version

3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21 65035912264e3acbced5a3e16793327f0a2f17bb

➜  blog  rails --version

Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

not

```
<%= form_for :article, url: create do |f| %>
```

For more info, check this [**form_for**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just scaffolding, you are answer should be more simple:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

Your form should work now...